# PostgreSQL count higher than Spark SQL

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, hadoop

When I try to Write a Dataframe to PostgreSQL using Spark Scala, I have noticed that the count on PostgreSQL is always higher than Spark Scala. I expected it to be same.

Is there any issue with Spark with PostgreSQL writes?

Writing to PostgreSQL

```
val connection="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5449/adb?user=aschema&password=abc" 
val prop = new java.util.Properties 
prop.setProperty("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") 
df.write.mode("Overwrite").jdbc(url=  connection, table = "adb.aschema.TABLE", connectionProperties  = prop)
```

My command to read count which is giving accurate count but PostgreSQL shows higher count.

```
sqlContext.read.option("compression","snappy")
    .parquet("/user-data/xyz/input/TABLE/").count
```

Comment: How does the code look like? How do you check the counts?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski , I count my data using --> sqlContext.read.option("compression", "snappy").parquet("/user-data/xyz/input/TABLE/").count

Comment: What about PostgreSQL? How do you write to postgresql? What's the Spark version?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Please see my updated question for code.

Comment: Your writing to postgresql does not use Spark SQL API at all so I'm closing your question as off-topic since there could be a couple of reasons why the results are different. Please think this issue through again and think whether you compare apples to apples.

Comment: I have corrected my Question, I thought my code is using the SQL related API here https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Comment: Where are you writing `df` into? Or where does `df` come from?